# Count rows with the specified value

Tags: php

I have a file (txt) with the following contents:

```
user1 2019-11-14 10:48:01
user2 2019-11-10 11:38:25
user3 2019-11-15 09:45:30
user4 2019-11-12 00:15:01
user5 2019-11-15 00:15:01
```

I want to count rows that are 24 hours befor of server time.
Unfortunately, I did not succeed by using the following code. Do you have a better solution?

```
<?php
$lines = file('user.txt');

foreach($lines as $line) {
        $section = explode(" ", $line);
        $lasttime = "$section[1]"." "."$section[2]";
        $timetosecend = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $lasttimetosecend = strtotime($lasttime);
        $count = 0;
        $countitem = $timetosecend-$lasttimetosecend<86400;

        if (strstr($line, $countitem)) {
            if (($timetosecend-$lasttimetosecend)>86400) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: is `if (strstr($line, $countitem)) {` ok? because you missing 1 parameter what to find. I think this is necessary. And you missing closing } under $count++;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code quite a bit, making use of the `limit` parameter to [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to avoid putting `$lasttime` back together, and only computing the current time once. As @NigelRen points out, we can compute the time a day ago and then we only have to check the sign of `$timetosecond - $lasttimetosecond`, which is more efficient:

```
$timetosecond = strtotime("now") - 86400;
$count = 0;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    list(, $lasttime) = explode(" ", $line, 2);
    $lasttimetosecond = strtotime($lasttime);
    if ($timetosecond - $lasttimetosecond < 0) {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mVtNQ)

Comment: @NigelRen firstly, thank you for the laugh, I needed that. Secondly thanks for the good suggestion, I've modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove if on the end.
You also need declared `$count` out of foreach because you rewrite count to 0 every time in the loop.

```
<?php
$lines = file('user.txt');
$count = 0; //  <-------------- here

foreach($lines as $line) {
        $section = explode(" ", $line);
        $lasttime = "$section[1]"." "."$section[2]";
        $timetosecend = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $lasttimetosecend = strtotime($lasttime); 
        $countitem = $timetosecend-$lasttimetosecend<86400;

        if ($countitem) {  // <---------- here
            $count++;
        }
    }
echo $count;
```